# The Download of Apps from the Mac App Store is very slow

Tags: macos, mac-appstore, data-transfer

I've wanted to download an app from the Mac App Store. But the download is much slower than normally.

What can I do?

Comment: Have you tried different internet connections?

Are other internet things slow?

Have you tried rebooting?

Go to speedtest.net - what speed do you get?

Answer (score 1):

To download with normal speed again, you can do the following trick:

(These first two steps weren't necessary for me and it worked for me without doing that.)

1. First open System Preferences → Network → Advanced and choose the tab "DNS" and add another DNS-Server by clicking on the <kbd>+</kbd>. A list of free DNS-Servers can be found at [about.com](http://about.com).
2. Now we choose a third Level DNS (Primary DNS 209.244.0.3, Secondary DNS 209.244.0.4)
3. Now we have to flush the DNS-Cache of the system, that OSX can use the new DNS-Servers.

   - *Command under Mavericks:*

     ```
     sudo dscacheutil -flushcache
     ```
   - *Command under Mountain Lion:*

     ```
     sudo killall -HUP mDNSResponder
     ```

The reason this may improve download speeds is that DNS servers may return endpoints to Apple's CDN according to the location they think you are coming from.  If you use a general one (not one from your ISP, or otherwise close to your location) you may get a CDN endpoint that is not optimal for you, resulting in slow/stalled downloads.

Comment: Also it would be helpful if you answered the **why** of needing to change DNS servers. The speed of DNS resolution may impact the speed at which a file begins downloading, but it should not have any affect once the file is downloading.